# Browser Compatibility Issues

Tags: html, css

I have a browser compatibility issues with this css code

nav {

```
  display: -webkit-box; 
  -webkit-box-orient:horizontal;    
  padding: 2% 0;    
  border-bottom: 1px solid #e6e6e6;     
  border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;        
  margin: 2% 0 2% 0;
```

}

nav a {

```
  font-family: 'GoudyRegular';  
  display:block;    -webkit-box-flex:1;         
  text-align:center;    
  font-size: 1.25;  
  color: #666;
```

}

and the html code is

```
<nav>
      <a href="about.html">About</a>
      <a href="#">Blog</a>
      <a href="work.html">Work</a>
      <a href="#">Contact</a>
</nav>
```

It displays as i want in Chrome but not in mozilla or internet explorer...Pls help

Comment: `-webkit-box-orient` is not for Firefox or IE. So you need to find the CSS styles for those browsers.

Answer (score 1):

Make it work across browsers like this:

`-webkit-box-orient:horizontal;

-moz-box-orient:horizontal;

-ms-box-orient:horizontal;

-o-box-orient:horizontal;

box-orient:horizontal;`